# android, room: is autogenerated primary key always monotonic

Tags: android, android-room

In my Android application I use Room library for persistency.

Assuming, I have an Entity defined like this:

```
@Entity(tableName = "my_entity")
public class MyEntity {

    @ColumnInfo(name = "id")
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    private int id;

    //...
}
```

can I rely on the fact, that `id` will be increased monotonically, i.e. that for newly inserted row `id` will always be higher, than for all previously created rows?

I think, that it is unlikely, but I can imagine, that Room (or SQLite - I am not sure, who is responsible in this case) could e.g. try to reuse the IDs of the previously deleted rows...

As far as I can see, the official documentation does not tell anything about it [`PrimaryKey.AutoGenerate()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room/PrimaryKey#autoGenerate()).

Comment: Pretty sure it uses sqlite autoincrement. Which does guarantee monotinocy. See here: https://sqlite.org/autoinc.html I'd look at the database file it created and check if the attribute is set

Comment: If a table has 3 items with ids (1,2,3). After removing last two and inserting one it becomes (1,4)

Comment: @Yeldar.N: The fact, that it is like this for the simple example does not prove, that it is always like this.

Comment: @JensV: Thank you for the link to the relevant SQLite docs. Indeed I looked at the generated schema json file and it has: `"createSql": "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `${TABLE_NAME}` (`id` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, ... <other fields>)"`, so according to the docs it should be guaranteed (by SQLite) to be monotonic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is the expanded comment from JensV.

As suggested by JensV, the generated schema json file contains (among others):

```
"createSql": "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `${TABLE_NAME}` (`id` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, ... <other fields>)"
```

So looking at the SQLite docs of [AUTOINCREMENT](https://sqlite.org/autoinc.html) we get, that it is guaranteed to be monotonic.

In fact, this flag serves exactly for this purpose: to ensure, that the generated value is monotonic (without this flag, the value still will be generated to be unique, but will not be necessarily monotonic). Taking into account, that Room uses the flag, it is strange, that they don't mention it in the documentation.